# Is word "turbo" old-fashioned?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, interpretation

I need to translate a childish insult "turbo-dweeb" (from English to Russian), and I'm a bit confused about the word "turbo".

There's a calque of "turbo" here in Russian. But if used as an insult, it sounds a bit outdated, like something said by a "cool kid" from the 90-th.

Does it have the same flavour in English, or is it neutral?

Comment: Translate from what language and into what language?

Comment: @CopperKettle, from English to Russian (added to the question)

Comment: *Turbo* is no more old fashioned as hundreds of thousands (millions?) than  other words in English, including related ones such as jet, engine, plane, turbine, etc. The term *turbo-dweeb* in English sounds cartoonish and 90ish, *ie*, old fashioned. To me, *dweeb* is the problematic word, as *nerd* has held up much better in usage among everyone except those who are 13 to 15 years old. In other words, *dweeb* sounds excessively silly and sophomoric.

Comment: NES, it was supposed to be silly. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: 1990s "old fashioned".  LOL

Comment: TRomano, uh, well, the fashions change pretty quickly? )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right about this sounding 90's-cool-kid-ish.

"Turbo" in this context is meant as: super/accelerated/ultra/hyper.

I.e. not just a normal dweeb, but a dweeb on steroids.